# Speed control table or floor fan prefer with thermostat

Tags: remote-control, arduino, home-electronics, fan-controller, smart-home

I have a floor fan with 3 speeds with ir remote. The remote broke but fan is too old to find a replacement remote. But that's not my problem. The fan has 3 speeds. Sometimes I wake up too cold or too hot. I would like the fan to have more speed control options than just 3. Would be even better if the fan can detect the temperature in the room and change it to the right speed to match. I could go with any diy option that is not too complex or an out of the box solution for my existing fan or something brand new as like a new fan.

1. I need a fan table or floor that has more than 3 speed options that can sense the temperature in the room and match the speed accordingly. Would like to have more speed options so I can get right speed instead of too cold or too hot.
2. I am in the USA. This could be a diy solution for my existing fan as long is its not too complicated or a diy solution for a new fan or if there is a fan that can do all this I can just purchase an our of the box solution.
3. I saw ceiling fan controllers but nothing for floor or table fan that is speed and not just on or off.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want something that is almost overkill, then you can't beat the [Dyson Pure](https://www.dyson.co.uk/air-treatment/purifiers) range.
I have one, they're great.
The big downside is the price point. Enough to put most people off.

They do, however, have everything you asked for & more.
Ten-speed, either manual or thermostatically-driven. Direct or diffuse modes, oscillator. Hot; cold; HEPA air filter; air quality & temperature monitoring, either 24/7 or only when on; humidifier [depending on model]. Night mode, sleep mode.

Simple line-of sight IR remote [included], or [free] iPhone/Android app, Alexa voice control etc.

& they look really cool too ;) no visible fan. You can put your arm right through the 'blower'.

[image]

No afilliation, merely a happy user.